# grails 3.1 - Failed to load latest version of profile [angular]

Tags: grails

Not sure where to go on this as I have setup proxy details using GRAILS_OPTS - can anyone suggest anything to try, please?

I thought profiles were bundled, so can you disable checking for latest profile versions, as a workaround?

Just downloaded grails 3.1 using sdkman (earlier grails versions wouldn't download, but other candidates e.g. groovy, did work - not sure what changed) and made it default candidate.

```
$ echo $GRAILS_OPTS
"-Dhttp.proxyHost=proxy, -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080, -Dhttp.proxyUser=me, Dhttp.proxyPassword=password, -Dhttps.proxyHost=proxy, -Dhttps.proxyPort=8080, -Dhttps.proxyUser=me, -Dhttps.proxyPassword=password"

Try to run grails and it bombs... 
$ grails --stacktrace --verbose
Resolving dependencies...
Error |
Failed to load latest version of profile [angular]. Trying Grails release version
org.springframework.boot.cli.compiler.grape.DependencyResolutionFailedException: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.DependencyResolutionException: Failed to collect dependencies at org.grails.profiles:angular:jar:3.1.0
        at org.springframework.boot.cli.compiler.grape.AetherGrapeEngine.resolve(AetherGrapeEngine.java:307)
        at org.springframework.boot.cli.compiler.grape.AetherGrapeEngine.grab(AetherGrapeEngine.java:112)
        at org.springframework.boot.cli.compiler.grape.AetherGrapeEngine.grab(AetherGrapeEngine.java:104)
        at org.grails.cli.profile.repository.MavenProfileRepository.getAllProfiles(MavenProfileRepository.groovy:128)
        at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.execute(GrailsCli.groovy:241)
        at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.main(GrailsCli.groovy:162)
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.DependencyResolutionException: Failed to collect dependencies at org.grails.profiles:angular:jar:3.1.0
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:380)
        at org.springframework.boot.cli.compiler.grape.AetherGrapeEngine.resolve(AetherGrapeEngine.java:302)
        ... 5 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.collection.DependencyCollectionException: Failed to collect dependencies at org.grails.profiles:angular:jar:3.1.0
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.collectDependencies(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:291)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:341)
        ... 6 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.grails.profiles:angular:jar:3.1.0
        at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:335)
        at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.readArtifactDescriptor(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:217)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.resolveCachedArtifactDescriptor(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:535)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.getArtifactDescriptorResult(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:519)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:409)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:363)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.process(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:351)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.collectDependencies(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:254)
        ... 7 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Could not transfer artifact org.grails.profiles:angular:pom:3.1.0 from/to grailsCentral (https://repo.grails.org/grails/core): Connect to repo.grails.org:443 timed out
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:444)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:246)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:223)
        at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:320)
        ... 14 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactTransferException: Could not transfer artifact org.grails.profiles:angular:pom:3.1.0 from/to grailsCentral (https://repo.grails.org/grails/core): Connect to repo.grails.org:443 timed out
        at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.ArtifactTransportListener.transferFailed(ArtifactTransportListener.java:43)
        at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$TaskRunner.run(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:355)
        at org.eclipse.aether.util.concurrency.RunnableErrorForwarder$1.run(RunnableErrorForwarder.java:67)
        at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$DirectExecutor.execute(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:581)
        at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector.get(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:249)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.performDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:520)
        at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:421)
        ... 17 more
Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to repo.grails.org:443 timed out
        at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:416)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:180)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:294)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:643)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:479)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:906)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.DecompressingHttpClient.execute(DecompressingHttpClient.java:137)
        at org.eclipse.aether.transport.http.HttpTransporter.execute(HttpTransporter.java:287)
        at org.eclipse.aether.transport.http.HttpTransporter.implGet(HttpTransporter.java:243)
        at org.eclipse.aether.spi.connector.transport.AbstractTransporter.get(AbstractTransporter.java:59)
        at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$GetTaskRunner.runTask(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:447)
        at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$TaskRunner.run(BasicRepositoryConnector.java:350)
        ... 22 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
        at java.net.TwoStacksPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:157)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:391)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:612)
        at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:414)
        ... 33 more

Error |
Failed to load latest version of profile [angular]. Trying Grails release version
org.eclipse.aether.resolution.DependencyResolutionException: Failed to collect dependencies at org.grails.profiles:angular:jar:3.1.0
```

Comment: Hi, have you found the solution? We are having similar problem trying to migrate from Grails 2.4.3 to Grails 3.1.4

Answer (score 1):

Gordon.

Meet the same issue. Looks like the Maven local repository files was broken during the development process.

To fix the problem remove all files from the folder (MacOS/Linux):

```
/Users/username/.m2/repository/org/grails/profiles/angular/3.1.0
```

(Windows)

```
C:\Documents and Settings\username\.m2\org\grails\profiles\angular\3.1.0
```

Then restart grails console.

Comment: I have tried grails 3.1.1 on a clean machine (Win 7 build, but still corporate behind firewall). I've been fighting proxy issues which are not fully resolved (finally got browser access to github re-enabled, but sdk can't update itself and can't install new grails versions) so I haven't been able to progress this...

Comment: recently installed from sdkman and yet had to delete some files from "angular/3.2.0.RC1"

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the following environment variable:
export JAVA_OPTS="-Dhttp.proxyHost=proxy.yourcompany.com -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080 -Dhttps.proxyHost=proxy.yourcompany.com -Dhttps.proxyPort=8080"

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried it but it made no difference - for me I also had to add the user and password options as I have to authenticate on the proxy

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what I'm talking about but I think grails is trying to do some ssh to github. 
If your proxy is blocking it, there is no way around it. 
I can clone from github with https, but not with ssh : see [github help](https://help.github.com/articles/which-remote-url-should-i-use/)
So i cannot grails create-app, etc.